# SDL Alternative with multiple windows and multiple display devices

Tags: c++

I'm looking for an alternative to SDL that supports multiple windows on multiple display devices for OpenGL.

Is there any mature library that provides this?

I'm aware taht SDL 1.3 will support this but it seems that's a bit into the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/index.php) is probably what you are looking for.

You should also take a look at [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg). It might seem like overkill, but it really is the best I've come across when it comes to rendering in multiple windows on multiple display devices. It's a complete graphics toolkit/engine, which might not be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Qt and its QGLWidget might be a good alternative, specially if you want to use a GUI with your OpenGL contexts.